# VideoJs-Record: How to taking image from Screen while screen share enabled

Tags: video.js, videojs-record

Salam,

I want to take images from the screen (whole screen, selected window or tab) while Screen share feature of the browser is activated.
This is my options for initializing VideoJs-Record:

```
var screenBlob = null;
var screenPlayer;
function initializeScreenCapture(isCaptureVideo, isWithAudio) {
    if (screenPlayer != null) {
        screenPlayer.record().destroy();
        //videojs('screen').dispose();
        $('#screen').remove();
        $("#screenTab").append('<video id="screen" playsinline class="video-js vjs-default-skin screen" style="background-color: #c3c4bc !important;"></video>');
    }

    isWithAudio = typeof (isWithAudio) == 'boolean' ? isWithAudio : true;

    var screenOptions = {
        controls: isCaptureVideo,
        /*width: 800,
        height: 450,*/
        fluid: false,
        bigPlayButton: false,
        controlBar: {
            volumePanel: isCaptureVideo && isWithAudio,
            fullscreenToggle: isCaptureVideo && isWithAudio
        },
        plugins: {
            record: isCaptureVideo ? {
                audio: isWithAudio,
                pip: true,
                screen: true,
                videoMimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=H264',
                displayMilliseconds: true
            } : {
                /*imageOutputType: 'dataURL',
                imageOutputFormat: 'image/png',
                imageOutputQuality: 0.92,
                image: {
                    // image media constraints: set resolution of camera
                    width: { min: 640, ideal: 640, max: 1280 },
                    height: { min: 480, ideal: 480, max: 920 }
                },
                // dimensions of captured video frames
                frameWidth: 640,
                frameHeight: 480*/

                video: false,
                audio: false,
                debug: true,
                    screen: true,
                    image: true,
                    frameWidth: 640,
                    frameHeight: 480
            }
        }
    };
    console.log(screenOptions);
    // apply some workarounds for certain browsers
    applyVideoWorkaround();
    applyScreenWorkaround();

    screenPlayer = videojs('screen', screenOptions, function () {
        // print version information at startup
        var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION + ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') + ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
        videojs.log(msg);
    });

    // error handling
    screenPlayer.on('deviceError', function () {
        console.warn('device error:', screenPlayer.deviceErrorCode);
    });

    screenPlayer.on('deviceReady', function () {
        const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('screen').getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        const stream = videoPlayer.captureStream();
        stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => {
            close()
        })
    });

    screenPlayer.on('error', function (element, error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    screenPlayer.on('startRecord', function () {
        screenPlayer.recordIndicator.show()
    });
    screenPlayer.on('stopRecord', function () {
        screenPlayer.recordIndicator.hide()
    });

    // snapshot is available
    screenPlayer.on('finishRecord', function () {
        // the blob object contains the image data that
        // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
        screenPlayer.recordIndicator.hide();
        console.log('screen recording ready: ', screenPlayer.recordedData);
        screenBlob = screenPlayer.recordedData;
        screenBlob.name = screenBlob.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '.mp4';
        $("#btnUploadScreen").show();
        stopScreenStream();
    });
}
```

I expect to show desktop screen when user setting "Capture image" switch on, for taking image and recording screen with/without audio by setting "Capture video" on.
[image: Displaying webcam image instead of Desktop Screen]